# How to customize numberpicker in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I implemented [numberpicker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/numberpicker) in my app.
I would like to modify the size of the numbers and the color of both highlighted value and those who are not. I managed to modify the highlighted ones wrapping it in the Theme widget and modifing the accentcolor, but don't know how I can do the other customizations?

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    accentColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  child: NumberPicker.integer(
    initialValue: _currentPickerValue,
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100,
    onChanged: (newValue) =>
      setState(() => _currentPickerValue = newValue)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I digged into the code and here is something that I found

- `selectedStyle = themeData.textTheme.headline.copyWith(color: themeData.accentColor);`
- `defaultStyle = themeData.textTheme.body1;` **This is ones which are not highlighted**

to change the size or color or any other style attribute modifiy those style.

here is an example code:

```dart
final theme = Theme.of(context);
Theme(
      data: theme.copyWith(
        accentColor: Colors.black,// highlted color
          textTheme: theme.textTheme.copyWith(
            headline5: theme.textTheme.headline5.copyWith(..), //other highlighted style
            bodyText2: theme.textTheme.headline5.copyWith(...), //not highlighted styles
      )),
      child: NumberPicker.integer(...),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you really much. I have to learn how to check this things too, without bothering others. Thank you again.

Comment: This is outdated at the moment. body1 was replaced with bodyText2 for the not highlighted numbers. For the highlighted, I was able to change their size with headline5, but I could not change the color somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Update your number picker package to the latest version.

```
new NumberPicker.integer(
                ...,
                selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(...),
                textStyle: TextStyle(...), //styles of the default text
          )
```

Visit [NumberPickec class](https://pub.dev/documentation/numberpicker/latest/numberpicker/NumberPicker-class.html) for study properties.